# Codeigniter - How to avoid multiple login of an user storing his session in database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm developing a web app with Codeigniter.

This app has a login page: i want to avoid that 2 people enter with the same credentials in the same moment. To do this i thought to store the value gotten from the function session_id() in my database. In this way, i can check in every page if the user has the same session_id stored in the db, if not he is logged out. This solution seems to work (i've tried using two browser) but seems like the value returned by session_id() changes over time.

What am i wronging? session_id() (explained [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata)) doesn't keep the same value for the whole session?

Does exist a better way to realize that?

Thank you in advance and sorry my english not perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the session is related to where and when u logged-in, not if the user logged in several times in ur app, so at least a way i solved this, considering:

1. The user can just close the browser and never execute a "log out function"
2. After some time the user may login from another browser
3. What about the `config['sess_match_ip']`

How to apply this considerations:

The user attemps a login typically a form that post a username and password

```
function logIn(){
  $user = $this->input->post('username');
  $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
  $autenticated = $this->SomeModelToLogin->logInFunction($user, $pass);
  //It depends on what you prefer but in the function that asks the db
  //if the user, exist, hash the password and whatever set the session
  //if not set it here like "first name", "last name", "data u may need", etc 


}
```

The function to logIn

```
function logInFunction($username, $password){
  //u can save a timestamp on the database when  the user logs in 
  //and u can ask that time like a "last_log_in_time"
  //or also use the session_id, if u are storing the session_id()
  //in your database u can compare that every time the person logs in 
  //or is using your application
  //and well here something like
  $dataReturned = $this->db
   ->query("SELECT * FROM USER where pass = $pass and username=$user");
  $this->session->nameOfTheUser = $dataReturned['name'];
  .....
  $this->session->setOtherStuff = $dataReturned['some_stuff'];
  //of he exist but is he logged in?
  //at some point u are saving the session_id to the row of the user
  //the u can ask to the database 
  $question = $this->db->select()
         ->from('USER')
         ->where('session_id', session_id())
         ->get()->num_rows();
  //now u decide if u want to destroy the session, update it whatever.
 //but u much check this every time the user is using the application 
 // if not he can just set the session and avoid the login page, and well, 
 //he can use the app
 //so try to make an function that check if the session_id matches one on the 
 //database and check it in the constructor if every controller, if it does   
 //not match just 
 /**
  $this->session->unset_userdata();
    $this->session->unset_userdata('is_client_login');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must- revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
    redirect(base_url());
  */

}
```

PS: I'm going to edit the answer when I get home I know I did not considered some points, order and stuff (hate cellphone keyboard)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is exactly what i do: i save session_id() in the database and check in every constructor of controllers if session_id() match with the saved one. If yes, it's okay, if not i call the sess_destroy(). The problem is that more calls of session_id() give me different result after a bit of time (without doing logout). How can i prevent this?

Comment: Oh, it does variate...ok then before saving the session_id() to the database, save it to ur current session like `$this->session->this_is_my_session_id = session_id()`, only time u call it, then when u call `$this->session->this_is_my_session_id` it will return u only the value that was once saved.

Comment: It solved the problem! At this point i could use also a simple uniqueid, saving it in session and in database!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, ty for the best answer vote, gonna try to edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, but uniqueid function is not meant to be used for security, try to hash something, some unique thing, this will surelly work on a small system for example i made a program that does something like u did, but its for a restaurant and 3 people use it...and its on a closed network, in those cases does not really matter, if u are going to have like 1000 users logging in persecond...then its an issue, so whats out with that.